# Dump mysql xampp from php localhost

Tags: php

My page is blank when I am dumping a MySQL database.

Here is the code:

```php
<?php
Exec('C:\Users\user\Desktop\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -h localhost -u root -p one test > C:\Users\user\desktop\newfile.sql')
?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The command line interaction works because you are prompted for the password. When connecting through your web portal the `-p` flag won't prompt for the password. You could resolve this by putting the password after the `-p`, presuming your web portal has security measures in place.

```
<?php
Exec('C:\Users\user\Desktop\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -h localhost -u root -pSECUREPASSWORDHERE one test > C:\Users\user\desktop\newfile.sql')
?>
```